# Displaying PHAssets (Photos) using PHCachingImageManager in SwiftUI app - IF statement in body View not working

Tags: swift, syntax, binding, swiftui, photo

I am trying to load a photo using `PHCachingImageManager` in my SwiftUI app. I am able to get the photo but unable to get my SwiftUI view to display it.

I have a view called `PhotoCell` as shown below. I pass the `Binding<UIImage>` to a function which uses `PHCachingImageManager` to load the asset. This works and returns a 90x120 image to the `Binding`'s set function. Inside the set function you can see that `hasLoadedImage` is set to `true`.

The `body` of the View is composed of an `if` statement. This is never executed except for the first time when the value of `hasLoadedImage` is `false`. I have no idea what else to do. Just as a test I replaced the `Image` inside the `if` with a `Text` but even that does not display once `hasLoadedImage` is set to `true`. I've used `if` statements frequently in `body` getters.

I feel like I've overlooked something obvious.

```swift
struct PhotoCell: View {

    @State var photoImage: UIImage = UIImage()
    @State var hasLoadedImage: Bool = false

    var photoAsset: PHAsset

    var photoBinding: Binding<UIImage> {
        Binding<UIImage>(
            get: {
                return self.photoImage
        },
            set: {(newValue) in
                print("Loaded image \(newValue.size)") // this prints with the correct size
                self.photoImage = newValue
                self.hasLoadedImage = true // seems to have no effect
        })
    }

    init(photoAsset: PHAsset) {
        self.photoAsset = photoAsset

        let options: PHImageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
        options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        options.resizeMode = .fast

        PhotosManager.shared.loadAsset(asset: photoAsset, size: CGSize(width: 48, height: 48), options: options, image: self.photoBinding)
    }

    var body: some View {
        if self.hasLoadedImage { // shouldn't this execute once the value is changed??
            return AnyView(
                Image(uiImage: self.photoImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
            )
        } else {
            return AnyView(
                Image(systemName: "goforward")
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To find real problem it is needed full testable code.

Answer (score 0):

So out of frustration I came up with a work-around which is actually simpler than what I was trying to do. I constructed a `UIViewRepresentable` wrapper for `UIImageView`:

```swift
struct MyImage: UIViewRepresentable {

    var photoAsset: PHAsset

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIImageView {
        let uiView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "goforward") ?? UIImage())
        return uiView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIImageView, context: Context) {
        let options: PHImageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
        options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        options.resizeMode = .fast

        PhotosManager.shared.loadAsset(asset: photoAsset, into: uiView, options: options)
    }
}
```

The `loadAsset` function is just this, if you want to test it, where `imageManager` is an instance of `PHCachingImageManager`. I would like to understand why my posted question is not working. I suspect it has something to do with the closure from `requestImage` and capturing `self` inappropriately but I just don't see it.

```
func loadAsset(asset: PHAsset, into imageView: UIImageView, options: PHImageRequestOptions?) {
        let size = CGSize(width: 48, height: 48)
        imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: { (result, info) in
            if let result = result {
                imageView.image = result
            }
        })
    }
```